# How to resolve path issue when you set params dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have params from client that i want to set to `readFile` path but its not setting variable when i invoke `readFile` method and returns empty array because its not reading the directory. How can i correct path issue ?

if i do this it works

```js
var filesData = {};
console.log('SEARCH ENV PRINTING', searchEnv);
if (searchEnv === 'DIT') {
  ditDirectory.readDirectory(function(files) {
    filesData.logFiles = files;
    filesData.searchEnv = searchEnv;
    asyncFiles(filesData);
  });
} else if (searchEnv === 'St') {
  stDirectory.readDirectory(function(files) {
    filesData.logFiles = files;
    filesData.searchEnv = searchEnv;
    asyncFiles(filesData);
  });
}
fs.readFile('logs/dit/'+ logfile.filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  console.log('inside readFile', data);
  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
});
```

does not work if i set `filesData.searchEnv` from user input

```js
fs.readFile('logs/' + filesData.searchEnv + '/'+ logfile.filename,
  'utf8',
  function (err, data) {
  console.log('inside readFile', data);
  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `filesData.searchEnv` contains correct value? Could you also give more thorough example pls (with where filesData come from).

Comment: Yes i am 100%  printing the values on console

Comment: You may use `path` (https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path) module to build valid paths (see `path.join`, `path.resolve`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really call things in the order you described, your `filesData.searchEnv` will contain nothing at the moment you call `fs.readFile`, because you assign value to it only in async callback of `readDirectory`.

Therefore, you have to either place file reading call into the callbacks or using promise to wait valid data.